# How to return a list as a string when calling a getter in a class instance

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have a class variable, a list, that can contain more than one value at a time (a MAC address). I would like to be able to return the value(s) as a comma-delimited string rather than a list. I know that I can do something like this:

```
class test(object):
     def __init__(self, mac):
         self.mac = mac

         @property
         def mac(self):
             return self.mac
             # return ','.join(map(str, self.mac))
         @mac.setter
         def mac(self, mac):
             self.mac = mac
             #self.mac = ','.join(map(str, mac))

     def macs_as_a_list(self):
         return ','.join(map(str, self.mac))

m1 = test(mac=['aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff', '11:22:33:44:55:66'])

m1.mac
  Out: ['aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff', '11:22:33:44:55:66']
  Desired: 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,11:22:33:44:55:66'
```

This works, of course:
`m1.macs_as_a_list()`

But, isn't there a way to make this conversion in the setter (or in the getter as demonstrated in the commented lines above)?

Comment: @AChampion If you only define a getter, you will not be able to set the attribute, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach is to use a private variable to store the raw value behind your property and to user your getter to format it accordingly.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, mac):
        self.mac = mac

    @property
    def mac(self):
        return ','.join(self._mac)

    @mac.setter
    def mac(self, mac):
        self._mac = mac


m1 = test(['aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff', '11:22:33:44:55:66'])
print(m1.mac) # 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,11:22:33:44:55:66'
```